# is it safe to remove i915-3.18-3.16-dkms after updating to Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: intel-graphics, 15.04

I installed latest Intel i915 drivers via Intel Graphic Installer (Ubuntu 14.10). After updating to Ubuntu 15.04, error regarding "i915-3.18-3.16-dkms" package appeared. Is it safe to remove this package now in Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: what error did you get exactly? dkms generates the kernel module automatically when you upgrade the kernel. You do not "need" it , but you will need to manually install the driver with each and every kernel upgrade.

Comment: Crash report /// Sorry, a problem occurred while installing software. /// Package: i915-3.18-3.16-dkms 1 /// That's all

Comment: Error appeared only three times (during upgrade to 15.04 and first time after logging). However, I removed the package and everything work just fine (so far)

Comment: just for information - for me, the error about i915 drivers appeard during upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04. it stated that I should check details about thet error in `/var/lib/dkms/i915-3.18-3.16/1/build/make.log`

Comment: Thanks, I had that same error ... I'll remove that package.